# How to run n processes simultaneously in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I am trying to execute n processes simultaneously. The example below works with 2 processes that are supplied externally.

At the moment it is all hard-coded for just these 2 processes but I would need to come up with the generic solution how to accomplish the same - i.e. run n processes at the same time.

My code is as follows:

```
import multiprocessing

'''

The first process: print 'aa'
The second Process: print 'BB'

'''

def TR1(): 
    print 'aaaaaaaaa'

def TR2(): 
    print 'BBBBBBBB'

if __name__ == '__main__':

    process_1 = multiprocessing.Process(name='process_1', target=TR1)
    process_2 = multiprocessing.Process(name='process_2', target=TR2)

    process_1.start()
    process_2.start()
```

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: If you are trying to learn Python, I would strongly recommend moving to Python 3 already. By the original timetable, Python 2 would be dead already; and you can clearly tell that experts and library maintainers are reluctant to continue to support the old version.

Comment: Unfortunately, on the project I am working on, there is just Python 2 service available.

Comment: What about starting your processes in a loop?

Comment: I am not sure if multiprocessing supports declaration of processes in a loop. If so, it looks like all of the functions (TR1(), TR2(), etc.) would also have to be created in a for loop...?

Comment: Then you need a list or generator for your functions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either spawn processes in a loop, or use executor pool.

In real life, later one is often preferred approach, as you can limit pool size *and* have easy result gathering.

If you're using python 2, there's [backport](https://pypi.org/project/futures/) including [`ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor)

Comment: Thanks for showing me the direction, I will check the pool of workers in multiprocessing [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)

Comment: A pool usually applies/maps the __same__ function to to the input, but distributes the input to n workers. According to your original question this is not what you want. Why is this the accepted answer?

Comment: This actually works as the processes are all of the same type so I can use it as: def p(arg):
    print arg

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(None)
    args = ['Hi', 'There', 'Whats up']
    r = pool.map_async(p, args)
    r.wait()

Comment: @jan-christoph-terasa can you please clarify for me, why _same_ function?

Comment: @Slam Hmm, reading the docs you can use `apply_async` to call your functions and arguments in a loop and they will evaluate without blocking. So yes, this answer is OK, if you use `apply_async` instead of `map` or the the blocking alternatives.

Comment: IIRC, executors should support `.submit`, but anyway – yes, `map` is not the only way